# D3.JS Grouped Donut Chart from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

So, I have [the following JSON data](http://pastebin.com/xQMRNFGQ) on my hands and I need to find the best way to graph a donut chart in D3.  Ignoring the "info" and "politicians" arrays and strictly focusing on the "industries" array for now, I want to achieve the following chart:

[image: Pardon the 2-minute Photoshop...]

Pardon the 2-minute Photoshop job...

Essentially each small black line represents an industry.  Each industry has an influence from Democrats, Republicans, and Independents in dollar amount.  I would like to create a donut chart (or two donut charts) divided by yeas and nays in the fashion above.

I have attempted to code a bit of this already and I'm still getting to know D3, so please bear with me.  That code looks like such:

```
d3.json('mock2.json', function(errors, data) {
//Formatting of data
var yeas = [];
var nays = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.industries.length; i++) {
    var yea_temp = {};
    var nay_temp = {};
    var yea_c = data.industries[i].yea_contribution;
    var nay_c = data.industries[i].nay_contribution;

    yea_temp.name = data.industries[i].name;
    yea_temp.influence = {"D": yea_c.d_influence, "R": yea_c.r_influence, "I": yea_c.i_influence};

    nay_temp.name = data.industries[i].name;
    nay_temp.influence = {"D": nay_c.d_influence, "R": nay_c.r_influence, "I": nay_c.i_influence};

    yeas.push(yea_temp);
    nays.push(nay_temp);
}

//Log the variables for console inspection
console.log(yeas);
console.log(nays);

//Declare variables
var width = 800,
    height = 600,
    radius = Math.min(width, height)/2;

var svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var group = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(300, 300)');

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(200)
    .outerRadius(radius);

var yea_pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d, i) {
        if(i == 0)
            return d.influence.D;
        else if(i == 1)
            return d.influence.I;
        else
            return d.influence.R;
    })
    .startAngle(-Math.PI/2)
    .endAngle(Math.PI/2);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(['rgba(92,188,239,0.5)', 'rgba(255,76,76,0.5)', 'rgba(150,163,170,0.5)']);

var yea_arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
    .data(yea_pie(yeas))
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc')
    .attr('class', function(d) { console.log(d); });

yea_arcs.append('path')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data); });
```

Thus far, I've only got the screen rendering a blue semi-circle, but it is divided up into three paths, so at least I know I'm looping correctly.  How can I sub-divide (for lack of a better word) these sections according to influence?

You'll note in the first bit of my code, that I essentially take the JSON that I've been given and try to format it a little bit nicer so it's easier in D3.  Is this best practice?  I feel that there's probably some magic function in D3 that makes all my worries go away, but I'm not aware of one.  Mostly I'm just seeking a little guidance (but code would certainly be nice!), so I'll take what I can get.

Also, [here's a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/wwwzY/) if you'd rather do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do stacked pie charts in D3.  I'm not entirely sure if this is the "correct" convention, but it certainly works well.  [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwwzY/1/) to follow along with.

I've restructured my `yeas` and `nays` arrays into specifying the data value at the first level (this way, D3 can properly loop) in an object and then also including party and name alongside.  Here's an example of how the `yeas` array looks:

[image: Yeas Array]

Essentially there's two arrays, `yeas` and `nays`, each having 9 objects withs values: `value`, `party`, and `name`.  This way I can pass `d3.layout.pie` the data of either of the arrays and give the `value` in that pie layout `d.value`.  More simply said, here's the code snippet to explain:

```
var yea_pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; })  //This computes a pie value for each yeas.value (d.value)
    .startAngle(-Math.PI/2)
    .endAngle(Math.PI/2);

var yeas_industry = yea_group.selectAll('.arc')
    .data(yea_pie(yeas))  //Pass the yeas variable to yea_pie
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'arc');
```

This is really the only solution I've ever seen to doing a stacked pie chart.  With that said, I'll mark this correct, but if any one else thinks of a better way, I'd be interesting in knowing.